# Failed to create javafx flatform in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javafx

[image: Netbeans Java Flatform error]

I got this error when I'm trying to create a Java Swing Application, by using Netbeans.
I really don't know how to fix this error. Internet did't give me a really good answer.
I Unistalled Netbeans & then reInstalled. but It doesn't work.
How can I fix this error. Thank you.

Comment: @ Gunawarden have you find the solution of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a NetBeans installation at hand, but have a look at your Java installations configured in NetBeans ("Java Platform Manager" in Tools menu?). Select the Java version you are using. There should be a JavaFX tab. I think you can disable it there, if you don't need it.

Note: If you're using the latest Java version from Oracle, then JavaFX should automatically be configured correctly, since JavaFX is now shipped with the JDK.